# Custom installer for OS X app

Tags: objective-c, macos, installation

I want to create a custom installer for OS X application with following provisions:

1. I have some resources. I want to allow user to select resources to be copied to bundle
2. Localised strings for installer UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are able to do it with QT installer framework where we need to do some changes in installer source code.

http://code.qt.io/cgit/installer-framework/installer-framework.git/tree